# application extending class's onCreate is not called on android 9

Tags: java, android, android-9.0-pie

I have an Application class, but the OnCreate method is not called on my Samsung S9 after i updated it to android 9 (Pie). All lower android versions work fine. even on my emulator with api 28 they work fine.  here's my onCreate() method

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    context = this;
    Realm.init(this);
    firstUsage = true;
}
```

Comment: DID  you add the name in your manifest file for the Application class?

Comment: yes i did and as i said it works fine in the emulator on api 28